# How to remove input prompt icon

Tags: html, css, validation, input

I want to remove input prompt icon, but I can't find any answer.

```
<input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter valid email address')" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email address" id="mce-EMAIL" class="email" required />
```

I add custom error message. Maybe exist any parameter for input to delete that icon. Do you know some resources how to style that input prompt.

[image]

Comment: Please share your working demo

Comment: This icon shows up only in chrome i guess.

Comment: I add input::-webkit-validation-bubble-icon {display: none !important;} but it doesn't work.

Comment: @FabianSchöner The bottommost comment on that answer mentions that it no longer works.

Comment: @MrLister that is indeed correct, but doesnt make this question less of a duplicate.